# Unable to get provider provider.com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase

[You can see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLogd.jpg)

Guys, anyone had similar problem? This happens only when I run my app on phones that have API<20...
And I already tried all suggested solutions regarding multiDex...